# Cookies across multiple TLDs?

Tags: cookies

I know how to make a cookie work across subdomains (set `.example.com` as the domain), but on my latest project I have multiple domains like so:

```
example.co.uk
example.net
example.biz
...
```

Is it possible to make cookies work across these domains? Semi-related, can I make `localStorage` work across these domains too?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies don't work that way. You would need to have at least two levels of the domain to be the same in order to use cookies eg- xyz.example.com and abc.example.com are common at 2 levels.