# ActionDispatch::Cookies are not set across domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a frontend React SPA interacting with a backend Rails API. In production, the frontend has a domain name `mysecretsite.com`, while the backend is associated with `mysecretsite.io`

I am using [ActionDispatch::Cookies](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html) to set access token in the browser, so that users can make subsequent requests with that token.

```
cookies.signed[:access_token] = { value: 'tmp_token_string', httponly: true, domain: :all }
```

It works as expected when React SPA and Rails API are both running locally in development on one computer.

After I had deployed React SPA and Rails API on different servers respectively, I noticed that cookies are not properly set in the browser.

I can reproduce such issue in development mode, where I placed React SPA on another computer within the same LAN.

I had tried configuring [ActionDispatch::Cookies](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html) parameters like `domain` with React SPA's `IP:Port` string for development environment,  or `%w(.mysecretsite.com .mysecretsite.io)` for production environment, or just `nil`,  but it did not change anything.

What could be missed in my cookie settings?

controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
    include ActionController::Cookies
end
```

config/application.rb

```
module RailsApp
   class Application < Rails::Application
       config.load_defaults 5.2
       config.api_only = true

       config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
   end
end
```

---

*24 hours later, I have some additional information:*

I took a look at the response header from Chrome browser. 
In the React SPA running on the same computer with Rails API, `access_token` cookie is properly set. And here is the response header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://192.168.12.40:27511
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
ETag: W/"ebd48cd3b0ac4fa7ba23a4d40b8508a2"
Vary: Origin
X-Request-Id: 9aa588f0-8569-b1ca-901945962e87
X-Runtime: 0.064807
```

While the React SPA running on another computer within the same LAN, `access_token` cookie is not set, as what happened in production. And here is the response header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://192.168.12.50:27511
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
ETag: W/"ebd48cd3b0ac4fa7ba23a4d40b8508a2"
Vary: Origin
X-Request-Id: 9aa588f0-8569-b1ca-901945962e87
X-Runtime: 0.059074
```

In both cases, `Set-Cookie` header is missing, but one of them successfully set the cookie, while the other failed.

Comment: What domains do you actually use? The `domain: :all` still requires that you use the same tld.

Comment: Can't say exactly what the domain name is, but the frontend has a domain name like `mysecretsite.com`, while the backend is associated with `mysecretsite.io`.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the issue myself. I just cannot assign `.com` domain to React API, while associate `.io` domain with Rails API.

The problem is that

> You would need to have at least two levels of the domain to be the same in order to use cookies

as mentioned in [Cookies across multiple TLDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15391241/cookies-across-multiple-tlds)

In development environment, when React SPA and Rails API are running on different hosts, my workaround is assigning a common local domain name to two applications respectively.

Firstly, edit `/etc/hosts` as something like:

```
192.168.12.40   mydevsite.com
192.168.12.10   api.mydevsite.com
```

Secondly in the Rails API app, add `mydevsite.com:27511` as an additional origin to the file `config/initializers/cors.rb`. And restart Rails API to take effect.

Lastly, update related request URLs in React SPA and the browser.

---

*24 hours later*

I can confirm that the issue has also been resolved in production environment, where Rails API is configured with a new domain name `api.mysecretsite.com`

However, I still have no idea why [the official documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html) has a setting example `domain: %w(.example.com .example.org)`, and what kind of use cases they are presenting.